# How to define a default argument value for a method in as2?

Tags: class, function, actionscript, actionscript-2

look at this code :

```
function a2j(trusted:Boolean=true):String
    {
... 
}
```

compiler will not accept this code in flash actionscript 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like AS2 doesn't force you to supply the all the arguments that a function declares. At the bottom of this [help page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000147.html), they state that arguments you do not supply are `undefined` ... and that any extra arguments you supply are ignored.

Also, the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972973/procedurally-accessing-a-functions-parameter-list-in-actionscript-2-0) shows that you can use the `arguments` keyword (an Array) to work with the parameters that are passed into the function.

So for a default value, as in your example above, you could do something like this:

```
function methodThatHasADefault(value:Boolean):void
{
    if (arguments.length == 0)
        value = true;

    // do something
}
```